# For "any" binary tree, what is the relation between all nodes and internal nodes

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

#### The original question is below.

For **any** binary tree with n nodes and i internal nodes, the relation between n and i is _____ <= i.

#### In my opinion

I thought n/2 <= i, but I can't not figure out what condition will let n/2 = i.
I also want to ask that the root node is internal node?

Answer (score 0):

In a full tree there are `1 + 2 + ... + 2^(h-1)` internal nodes and `2^h` leaf nodes (where `h` is the height of the tree).

That means the total number of nodes is

```
n = 1 + 2 + .... + 2^h = 2^(h+1)-1
i = 1 + 2 + ... + 2^h-1 = 2^h - 1
```

Now, for the relation you are looking for:

```
n-i = 2^h+1 - 1 - 2^h + 1 = 2^h+1 - 2^h = 2*2^h - 2^h = 2^h
```

Since `2^h = i+1`, you get:

```
n - i = i+1
n - 1 = 2i
(n - 1)/2 = i
```

(Note that there is no issue with non integer result, since `n` is always odd in full tree).

Now, all you have left to show is that full tree is indeed the one with the highest such ratio (this is left for the reader).